# How can I sort a list of ActiveRecords by an attribute length?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, rails-postgresql

I have an object like this:

```
irb(main):076:0> hints = Hint.where("sentence LIKE ?","%你%")
  Hint Load (4.0ms)  SELECT "hints".* FROM "hints" WHERE (sentence LIKE '%你%')
[
    [0] #<Hint:0x007fb99c6520b8> {
                :id => 214,
          :sentence => "我为你们立下模范，我向你们怎样做，你们也该照样做。",
              :user => nil,
           :learned => nil,
        :created_at => Sun, 06 Jan 2013 18:14:33 UTC +00:00,
        :updated_at => Sun, 06 Jan 2013 18:14:33 UTC +00:00
    },
    [1] #<Hint:0x007fb99c659a70> {
                :id => 229,
          :sentence => "他快要完成地上的传道工作时，曾向耶和华祷告说“我已经使他们使徒认识你的名，以后还要使他们认识”。",
              :user => nil,
           :learned => nil,
        :created_at => Sun, 06 Jan 2013 18:43:23 UTC +00:00,
        :updated_at => Sun, 06 Jan 2013 18:43:23 UTC +00:00
    },
    [2] #<Hint:0x007fb99c659458> {
                :id => 234,
          :sentence => "你的王到你这里来了。",
              :user => nil,
           :learned => nil,
        :created_at => Sun, 06 Jan 2013 18:48:12 UTC +00:00,
        :updated_at => Sun, 06 Jan 2013 18:48:12 UTC +00:00
    }
]
irb(main):077:0> hints.class
ActiveRecord::Relation < Object
```

How can I sort by `sentence` length?

My final goal is to make it so that when someone clicks on a Chinese character in a lesson that they will be shown a few of the shortest example sentences available as a hint to the meaning of the character.

I am using PostgreSQL.

Comment: If you want a SQL solution, it will likely have to be database-specific; so, what DB are you using?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

this sort:

```
hints = hints.sort { |x,y| x.sentence.length <=> y.sentence.length }
```

will do the job

Answer (score 20):

Sameera207 has the right idea,
but giving you the answer as ruby code.

```
Hint.where("sentence LIKE ?","%你%").order("LENGTH(sentence) ASC")
```

This will solve your problem

Perhaps you want a method like this;

```
def shortest_example(word)
  Hint.where("sentence LIKE ?", "%#{word}%").order("LENGTH(sentence) ASC").first
end
```

Comment: I want to make a jquery .on("click") function that will query the database with 'this' and then display the results in a growl-like notification (using freeow or meow). I am new to rails, but even newer to ajax. Can you point me in the right direction for getting ajax to pull the data that your method pulls? Even just helping me know what to search for on google will help. I have tried searching, but I don't know the correct terminology.

Comment: Sounds like you want to add an action "shortest_example" on your Words controller, that takes a word, and returns the example. You should look at `link_to :remote => true`. I suggest you also read a book like `Rails 3 in Action`.

Answer (score 6):

I think the easy way is to do your sorting from the DB end, as an example in MySQL:

```
order by LENGTH(sentence) desc
```

even you could write a scope for this.

Because as I can see, if you are trying to sort it after the DB select, it will be another loop which is unnecessary.

Comment: OP is not using MySQL, but this is valid for PostgreSQL as well.

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
hints = Hint.find_by_sql("SELECT * FROM hints WHERE sentence LIKE('%你%') ORDER BY LENGTH(sentence) ASC")
```

Comment: ```irb(main):091:0> hints.find_by_sql("SELECT * FROM hints WHERE sentence LIKE("%你%") ORDER BY LENGTH(sentence) DESC")``` gave me ```NameError: undefined local variable or method `你' for main:Object``` and ```Hint.find_by_sql("SELECT * FROM hints WHERE sentence LIKE("%你%") ORDER BY LENGTH(sentence) DESC")``` gave the same error.

Comment: Try it with an English word and see what happens--maybe an encoding issue we need to solve

Comment: I'm trying it locally on my IRB and not getting an error:

`Hint.find_by_sql("SELECT *  FROM hints WHERE sentence LIKE '%你%' ORDER BY LENGTH(sentence) ASC")`

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't able to get .order to work in my rails query. I needed to use .reorder instead this was for children of model.

E.g

```
doc_glossaries = doc.doc_glossaries.where(active: true, trashed: false).reorder("LENGTH(src) DESC")
```